# String format double with arbitrary precision, fixed decimal position

Tags: c#, string, c#-4.0, formatting, string-formatting

I want to write a function that takes in 4 arguments, and prints out a string satisfying the following conditions:

1. The decimal should be in string position X (where X is constant).  That way, when I
   print a series of such strings, the decimal position always lines
   up.
2. In practice, the double has usually up to 5 digits on the left of the decimal place, including the negative sign. and up to 7 digits on the right of the decimal place.
3. The other fields are left-justified and have fixed column widths.

So far I have been able to deal with 3 of the 4 columns; however, I am having trouble with the decimal argument.  I can't seem to figure out how to combine arbitrary precision with a fixed decimal place.  Here is what I've got so far:

```
public String PrintRow(string fieldName, string fieldUnit, double value, string description){ 
    return string.Format(
        " {0,4}.{1,-4}        {2,8:####0.0000####} : {3,-25}\n", 
        fieldName, fieldUnit, value, description);
}
```

Here are some example outputs that I'd like to be able to make:

```
 STRT.M            57.4000                 : Start
 STOP.M           485.8000                 : Stop
 STEP.M             0.1524                 : Step
 SMTN.FT         -111.2593615              : Something Cool
```

What should I do?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Is this code supposed to adjust formatting based on the entire dataset? Or do you want to specify the position of the decimal point and the number of digits as parameters?

Comment: Basically, just make it so that the decimal place is always in a fixed position.  It should be capable of arbitrary precision in either direction

Comment: in the double token {2:0.#######}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give you what you want:

```
public static string PrintRow(string token, string unit, double value, string desc)
{
    // convert the number to a string and separate digits
    // before and after the decimal separator
    string[] tokens = value
        .ToString()
        .Split(new string[] { CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    // calculate padding based on number of digits
    int lpad = 11 - tokens[0].Length;
    int rpad = 19 - tokens[1].Length;

    // format the number only
    string number = String.Format("{0}{1}.{2}{3}",
        new String(' ', lpad),
        tokens[0],
        tokens[1],
        new string(' ', rpad));

    // construct the whole string
    return string.Format(" {0,-4}.{1,-4}{2}  : {3,-23}\n",
        token, unit, number, desc);
}
```

Comment: +1, although you could write the entire OP's method to make it clearer what you're doing (not just the number part). And it's culture dependent: the right way would be to use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator` as the decimals separator when splitting the number.

Comment: @Groo I took the liberty of doing so myself - and I included the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator` too.  See answer below.